# Django 1.10 shows a square bracket in display of the form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm quite new to django and i'm now creating my forms for uploading data in the database. I'm using django 1.10 and python 2.7

I have a upload.html in my templates. And then i

```
<div class="form">]
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'upload' %}" enctype=multipart/form-data >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- This line inserts a CSRF token. -->
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
            <!-- This line displays lines of the form. -->
        </table>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

A part of my forms.py

```
class Form_inscription(forms.Form):
     study = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Choose the study of the database file", queryset=Study.objects.all(),
                               initial=Study.objects.all()[:1].get().id)
     databasefile = forms.FileField(label="Database file")
     assay = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Choose the assay", queryset=LookUpAssay.objects.all(),
                               initial=LookUpAssay.objects.all()[:1].get().id)

     readout = forms.ChoiceField(label="Choose the readout, choose --- if assay contains all readouts", choices=readouttuple)
     rawdatafile = forms.FileField(label ="Choose the raw data file")
```

It then displays this with the square bracket. and i have no idea why.

]

Choose the study of the database file:
Database file:
Choose the assay:
Choose the readout, choose --- if assay contains all readouts:
Choose the raw data file:

Could someone shed a light on this weird problem?
Thanks in advance,
Dani

Comment: In you html `<div class="form">]` , why `]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not your form, its your html. Theres a square bracket lurking somewhere in there:

```
<div class="form">] 
#                 ^
```

Comment: hahaha thank you... totally didn' t see that i've been staring at it for a couple of days....I feel so dumb rght now. But i really couldn' t find it.